# move uploaded file failed to open stream: No such file or directory PHP

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES['file'])) 
    { 
      
      $original_url='adminPanel/Images/';
      $currentDate = new DateTime();
      $currentTimestamp = $currentDate->format("YmdHis");
      $randomNumber= mt_rand(1111, 9999);
      $filePath=$_FILES['file']['name'];
      $fileName = $currentTimestamp.$randomNumber.$filePath;
      $source = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
      $ext = end((explode(".", $filePath)));//take extension from image/video 
      $fileName = $currentTimestamp.$randomNumber.".".$ext;  
      $original = $original_url.$fileName;  
         move_uploaded_file($source,$original ); 
    }
    
?>
```

> PHP Warning:
> move_uploaded_file(adminPanel/Images/201704210824047891.JPG): failed
> to open stream: No such file or directory in
> G:\PleskVhosts\sinnonteq.com\qhawk.sinnonteq.com\adminPanel\Product.php
> on line 19
>
> PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
> 'C:\Windows\Temp\phpC5EE.tmp' to
> 'adminPanel/Images/201704210824047891.JPG' in
> G:\PleskVhosts\sinnonteq.com\qhawk.sinnonteq.com\adminPanel\Product.php
> on line 19

Comment: Most likely the target folder `adminPanel/Images/` but is on a different level in the physical file tree.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not answering the question before the edit.

**Updated answer**

It is good practice to check if the files and locations you are you using exist.

You can use `is_file()` to check if the file exists or `is_uploaded_file()` to check if the file exists and it is uploaded by HTTP POST if the source file exists.

And you can use `is_dir()` to check if the target folder exists.

If it does not exist you can create it first with `mkdir()`

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, is it? It should have been a comment, maybe.

Comment: Low reputation members can't comment